# Subset both column-wise and row-wise?

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, logic, subset

I have example data as below (real data is 150x200), and need to keep the best combination of rows and columns that would give me *least* NAs. I could use `complete.cases()` but it removes too many rows.

Just by looking at this example, it is obvious to exclude row **x6** as it has most `NA` count. Similarly, we can exclude column **A** and **F**, as they have most `NA` count.

Need some hint on logic, doesn't have to be full code solution.

```
#reproducible data
df <- read.csv(text="
SampleID,A,B,C,D,E,F
x1,NA,x,NA,x,NA,x
x2,x,x,NA,x,x,NA
x3,NA,NA,x,x,x,NA
x4,x,x,x,NA,x,x
x5,x,x,x,x,x,x
x6,NA,NA,NA,x,NA,NA
x7,x,x,x,NA,x,x
x8,NA,NA,x,x,x,x
x9,x,x,x,x,x,NA
x10,x,x,x,x,x,x
x11,NA,x,x,x,x,NA")

# complete cases
df[ complete.cases(df),]
#   SampleID A B C D E F
#5        x5 x x x x x x
#10      x10 x x x x x x
```

**Additional info**:
This is a data for risk calculation, rows are samples and columns are variables. Each variable has a risk factor of some value. Risk predicting algorithm (computed using different custom software) can work with say, with 5 variables or with 200. The more variables will give obviously more reliable answer. To be able to have comparable results most samples should have most overlapping variables. I will need to keep at least ~60% of samples - rows.

Comment: You could use `sum(is.na(...))`... but without understanding what you're trying to do and what your criteria is for "too many NA" it is hard to come up with a reasonable answer...

Comment: Building on Justin's suggestion, I would recommend using row and col sums and define a function that specifies your threshold of too many.

Comment: Without further requirements, I don't think this is a solvable problem.  E.g. what's the minimum subset you need, does it have to be contiguous, and most important: what are you trying to achieve?  How do you justify removing some data but not others on the basis of `NA` values which have no apparent causal relationship?

Comment: Agree, question is vague... desired output would be: if you keep columns `x,y,z` and rows `5,8,9,20` you will have least `NA` count proportion to all data.

Comment: Still not helpful: you could remove **all** rows and columns with one or more `NA` to get the maximum possible ratio.  Doubtful that will give you a valid analysis.  What do your data mean in the first place?

Comment: Additional info added, hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting - you may be looking for a variant of edge-connectedness, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630521/grouping-a-many-to-many-relationship-from-a-two-column-map  (thanks to Blue Magister for identifying this link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function for you to play with. Hopefully it's something you can modify to suit your needs:

```
almostComplete <- function(dataset, rowPct, colPct = rowPct, n = 1) {
  if (sum(is.na(dataset)) == 0) out <- dataset
  else {
    CS <- colSums(is.na(dataset))/ncol(dataset)
    RS <- rowSums(is.na(dataset))/nrow(dataset)
    if (is.null(rowPct)) rowPct <- head(sort(RS, decreasing=TRUE), n)[n]
    if (is.null(colPct)) colPct <- head(sort(CS, decreasing=TRUE), n)[n]

    dropCols <- which(CS >= colPct)
    dropRows <- which(RS >= rowPct)
    out <- dataset[setdiff(sequence(nrow(dataset)), dropRows),
                   setdiff(sequence(ncol(dataset)), dropCols)]
  }
  out
}
```

A few examples...

Drop whichever row and column have the highest percentage of NA values:

```
almostComplete(df, NULL, NULL)
#    SampleID    B    C    D    E
# 1        x1    x <NA>    x <NA>
# 2        x2    x <NA>    x    x
# 3        x3 <NA>    x    x    x
# 4        x4    x    x <NA>    x
# 5        x5    x    x    x    x
# 7        x7    x    x <NA>    x
# 8        x8 <NA>    x    x    x
# 9        x9    x    x    x    x
# 10      x10    x    x    x    x
# 11      x11    x    x    x    x
```

Drop the rows and columns which have more than the second highest percentage of NA values.

```
almostComplete(df, NULL, NULL, n = 2)
#    SampleID    B    C    D E
# 2        x2    x <NA>    x x
# 4        x4    x    x <NA> x
# 5        x5    x    x    x x
# 7        x7    x    x <NA> x
# 8        x8 <NA>    x    x x
# 9        x9    x    x    x x
# 10      x10    x    x    x x
# 11      x11    x    x    x x
```

Set one threshold value for both rows and columns.

```
almostComplete(df, .7)
#    SampleID    B    C    D    E
# 1        x1    x <NA>    x <NA>
# 2        x2    x <NA>    x    x
# 3        x3 <NA>    x    x    x
# 4        x4    x    x <NA>    x
# 5        x5    x    x    x    x
# 6        x6 <NA> <NA>    x <NA>
# 7        x7    x    x <NA>    x
# 8        x8 <NA>    x    x    x
# 9        x9    x    x    x    x
# 10      x10    x    x    x    x
# 11      x11    x    x    x    x
```

Specify row and column threshold values separately.

```
almostComplete(df, .2, .5)
#    SampleID    B    C    D E
# 2        x2    x <NA>    x x
# 4        x4    x    x <NA> x
# 5        x5    x    x    x x
# 7        x7    x    x <NA> x
# 8        x8 <NA>    x    x x
# 9        x9    x    x    x x
# 10      x10    x    x    x x
# 11      x11    x    x    x x
```

Not knowing exactly how you're going to use this, I'm not sure if this is useful or not....

Comment: This is funny, while waiting I came up to almost the same solution, of course mine is not as beautifully packed into function as yours, thank you AnandoMahto.

Comment: @zx8754, cool. It was an interesting problem to think about, especially providing an "automatic" setting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `apply` with the function :

```
count.na <- function(vec) { return (length(which(is.na(vec)))) }
```

And finaly choose colums and rows with a percentage of NA