# Dynamically group rows by their values

Tags: excel, hyperlink, match, grouping, formula

I am looking for a way to group rows by linking the values of the cells (see link for image). For example, Row 1 is linked to row 2 by the letter "B", and row 2 is linked to row "3" by the letter C -- making those three rows group 1. Whereas, row 4 has no links and is considered group 2.

[Example image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29079095/Excel.jpg)

UPDATE: When I say 'linked' I mean that rows can be grouped by a common value in a cell. Given my first example, the letter "B" is present in both row 1 and row 2, which I then consider 'linked'. See the next link for a sub-sample of my original, but more complex, data.

[Sub-sample of original data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29079095/Excel_Data.xlsx)

I apologize in advance if this question has been addressed in an earlier post but I simply don't know how to phrase it.

Comment: Can you explain better when you consider rows "linked". It is always "the value in column B is the value in column A for the next row"? Do you want (sequential) row numbering like you did in your image?

Comment: Is this like a clustering-problem? Those are normally incremental, so I would say you would need to use VBA for that...

Comment: @akdadevil - I believe you are right - although it may be possible to do this somewhat more efficiently by creating an nxn table with ones at the intersection of existing `A` and `B` values...

Comment: possible duplicate of [identify groups of linked episodes which chain together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135971/identify-groups-of-linked-episodes-which-chain-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a way of solving this problem using R and the RBGL package. Really appreciate everyone's input. See link...

[identify groups of linked episodes which chain together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135971/identify-groups-of-linked-episodes-which-chain-together)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (if I understand your problem) - Assuming you have data in columns A and B, and group numbers in C.

Put the number `1` in the first row, "group" column (cell C1).  Then put the following formula in cell `C2`, and drag down:

```
=IF(B1 = A2, C1, C1 + 1)
```

when the cells match, the group number is the same, otherwise it increments.  Simple sample:

[image]

Formula view of the same thing:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, Floris. When I say 'linked' I mean that rows can be grouped by a common value in a cell. Given my first example, the letter "B" is present in both row 1 and row 2, which I then consider 'linked'. I tried your formula suggestion, and it works if the columns are sorted in a logical order, but my data are sometimes not in a logical order. Here is a link of a sample of my original, but more complex, data (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29079095/Excel_Data.xlsx). I apologise if I'm not making much sense.

Comment: No it makes sense... But that is a much harder problem. I suggest you update the question with the additional detail. It looks like you are trying to find parts of a linked list that belong together... How big do the numbers get? If its no more than a few 100 I may have some ideas... Otherwise algorithm becomes n^2 ...