# To find number of patterns

Tags: r, graph-theory, subgraph, edge-list

For a dataset like:

```
21 79 
78 245 
21 186 
65 522 
4 21 
3 4 
4 212 
4 881 
124 303 
28 653 
28 1231 
7 464 
7 52 
17 102 
16 292 
65 837 
28 203 
28 1689 
136 2216 
7 1342 
56 412
```

I need to find the number of associated patterns. For example 21-79 and 21-186 have 21 in common. So they form 1 pattern. Also 21 is present in 4-21. This edge also contributes to the same pattern. Now 4-881, 4-212, 3-4 have 4 in their edge. So also contribute to the same pattern. Thus edges 21-79, 21-186, 4-21, 4-881, 4-212, 3-4 form 1 pattern. Similarly there are other patterns. Thus we need to group all edges that have any 1 node common to form a pattern (or subgraph). For the dataset given there are total 4 patterns.

I need to write code (preferably in R) that will find such no. of patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're describing the data as subgraphs, why not use the `igraph` package which is very knowledgeable about graphs. So here's your data in data.frame form

```
dd <- structure(list(V1 = c(21L, 78L, 21L, 65L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 124L, 
  28L, 28L, 7L, 7L, 17L, 16L, 65L, 28L, 28L, 136L, 7L, 56L), V2 = c(79L, 
  245L, 186L, 522L, 21L, 4L, 212L, 881L, 303L, 653L, 1231L, 464L, 
  52L, 102L, 292L, 837L, 203L, 1689L, 2216L, 1342L, 412L)), .Names = c("V1", 
  "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

We can treat each value as a vertex name so the data you provide is really like an edge list. Thus we create our graph with

```
library(igraph)
gg <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(dd$V1), as.character(dd$V2)), 
    directed=F)
```

That defines the nodes and vertex resulting in the following graph (`plot(gg)`)

[image: graph data]

Now you wanted to know the number of "patterns" which are really represented as connected subgraphs in this data. You can extract that information with the `clusters()` command. Specifically,

```
clusters(gg)$no
# [1] 10
```

Which shows there are 10 clusters in the data you provided. But you only want the ones that have more than two vertices. That we can get with

```
sum(clusters(gg)$csize>2)
# [1] 4
```

Which is 4 as you were expecting.

Comment: This is admittedly a tough issue to search for, but is it the same problem as my old question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135971/identify-groups-of-linked-episodes-which-chain-together ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah my question is similar to the one posted on ^this link. But I am getting an error when I tried to include the library igraph: "there is no package called 'igraph'". Can you help me here?

Comment: @phoenix If you don't have the library, you will need to install it first. Just run `install.packages("igraph")` inside R.