# filter a df with NA to get only individuals that appear more than one time in r

Tags: r, filter, panel, na

I am using a national survey to run a regression: the survey is conducted every two years and some individual are repeatedly interviewed while others just one time.

Now I want to make the df a panel one (have only the individual that appears more than one time). The df is like this:

```
year  nquest nord nordp sex age
  2000   10    1     1   F  40
  2000   10    2     2   M  43
  2000   30    1     1   M  30
  2002   10    1     1   F  42
  2002   10    2     2   M  45
  2002   10    3     NA  F  15
  2002   30    1     1   M  32
  2004   10    1     1   F  44
  2004   10    2     2   M  47
  2004   10    3     3   F  17
  2004   50    1     NA  M  66
```

where nquest is the code number of the family, nord is the code number of the individual and nordp is the code number that the individual had in the previous survey; when a new individual is interviewed the value in nordp is "missing" (R automatically insert NA). For example the individual 3 of family 10 has nordp=NA in 2002 because it is the first time that she is interviewed, while in 2004 nordp is 3 (because 3 was the number that she had in 2002).

I can't use nord to filter the df because the composition of the family may change (for example in 2002 in family x the mother has nordp=2 (it means that in 2000 nord was 2) and nord=2 but the next year nord could be 1 (for example if she gets divorced) but nordp is still 2).

I tried to filter using this command:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(nquest, nordp)
filter(n()>1)
```

but I don't get the right df because if for the same family there are more than one individual insert (NA) they will be considered as the same person since nordp is NA  the first time.

How can I consider also the individual that appears for the first time in a certain year (nordp=NA)? I tried to a create a command using age (the age in t shoul be equal to (age (in t-2) + 2; for example in 2000 age is 20, in 2002 is 22) but it didn't worked.

Consider that the df is composed by thousand observations and I can't check manually.

The final `df` should be:

```
  year  nquest nordp sex age
  2000   10      1        F  40
  2000   10      2        M  43
  2000   30      1        M  30
  2002   10      1        F  42
  2002   10      2        M  45
  2002   10      3        F  15
  2002   30      1        M  32
  2004   10      1        F  44
  2004   10      2        M  47
  2004   10      3        F  17
```

As you can see there are only the individual that appears more than one time and `nquest=10 nordp=30` appears three times; with my command it appears just two times because in the first year `nordp` was `NA`.

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on the example

Comment: So are you telling that a given combination of `nquest,nord` *does not* identify a person? If that's the case, you should change you way to store data. It's much better to have an id for the family and one for the individual which is unique and not dependent on the family, so you can identify the person just from the id and not from the combo family-person.

Comment: @akrun I wrote in the answer because I couldn't insert the df there

Comment: @nicola maybe I didn't explain well: the combination of nquest and nord identify a person but it is possible that from one year to another it doesn't actually identify the same person; 

for example: in 2000 family x is composed by man (nord=1, nordp=1) and woman (nord=2, nordp=2), so nquest=x, nord=1 identify the man; suppose they get divorced in 2002 and only the woman is interwied, in this case nquest = x, nord = 1 and nordp=2 so the combination nquest=x, nord=1 identify the woman. 
For this reasone I can't use nord to filter, but at the same time I have the problem of NA in nordp

Comment: So it doesn't. Not a good way to store data.

Comment: I second @nicola's point.  Suppose you manage to filter out people who only appear once; how then are you going to use the panel structure of the data? Ultimately you would need a way to identify unique persons (possibly using the chain of `nord` and `nordp`s).

Comment: Note that with your example data, it's relatively easy to include individuals that appear more than once, by creating a year-of-birth field and then grouping by family code, sex, and year-of-birth. But this method fails if e.g. we have twins.

Comment: @WeihuangWong thank you, I will try taking into consideration year of birth; if they are twins nord o nordp will be different because they are two different individuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to assign unique IDs to individuals, then filter by the count of unique IDs.  The main idea is to chain together the `nordp` and `nord` values within each family over years. Here's an idea inspired by [Identify groups of linked episodes which chain together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135971/identify-groups-of-linked-episodes-which-chain-together).  First, load the `igraph` package, via `library(igraph)`. Then the following function assigns IDs for a given family.

```
assignID <- function(d) {
  fields <- names(d) # store original column names
  d$nordp[is.na(d$nordp)] <- seq_len(sum(is.na(d$nordp))) + 100
  d$nordp_x <- (d$year-2) * 1000 + d$nordp
  d$nord_x <- d$year * 1000 + d$nord
  dd <- d[, c("nordp_x", "nord_x")]
  gr.test <- graph.data.frame(dd)
  links <- data.frame(org_id = unique(unlist(dd)),
                      id = clusters(gr.test)$membership)
  d <- merge(d, links, by.x = "nord_x", by.y = "org_id", all.x = TRUE)
  d$uid <- d$nquest * 100 + d$id
  d[, c(fields, "uid")]
}
```

The function can "tell", for example, that

```
year  nordp  nord
2000      1     1
2002      1     2
2004      2     3
```

is the same individual, by chaining together the `nordp` and `nord` over the years, and assigns the same unique ID to all 3 rows.  So, for example,

```
assignID(subset(df, nquest == 10))
#   year nquest nord nordp sex age  dob  uid
# 1 2000     10    1     1   F  40 1960 1001
# 2 2000     10    2     2   M  43 1957 1002
# 3 2002     10    1     1   F  42 1960 1001
# 4 2002     10    2     2   M  45 1957 1002
# 5 2002     10    3   101   F  15 1987 1003
# 6 2004     10    1     1   F  44 1960 1001
# 7 2004     10    2     2   M  47 1957 1002
# 8 2004     10    3     3   F  17 1987 1003
```

gives us an additional column with the `uid` for each individual.

The remaining steps are straightforward.  We split the dataframe by `nquest`, apply `assignID` to each subset, and `rbind` the output:

```
dd <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df$nquest, assignID))
```

Then we can just group by `uid` and filter by count:

```
dd %>% group_by(uid) %>% filter(n()>1)
# Source: local data frame [10 x 8]
# Groups: uid [4]

#     year nquest  nord nordp    sex   age   dob   uid
#    <int>  <int> <int> <dbl> <fctr> <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1   2000     10     1     1      F    40  1960  1001
# 2   2000     10     2     2      M    43  1957  1002
# 3   2002     10     1     1      F    42  1960  1001
# 4   2002     10     2     2      M    45  1957  1002
# 5   2002     10     3   101      F    15  1987  1003
# 6   2004     10     1     1      F    44  1960  1001
# 7   2004     10     2     2      M    47  1957  1002
# 8   2004     10     3     3      F    17  1987  1003
# 9   2000     30     1     1      M    30  1970  3001
# 10  2002     30     1     1      M    32  1970  3001
```

Comment: thank you very much! I tried to filter in another way using day of birth but you're solution is the best one, just what I needed! Thank you!