# Search string sequentially in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

```
id1   id2    date

101   NA      01.1.2021     
102   101     12.1.2021
103   102     17.1.2021
104   103     18.1.2021
105   NA      25.1.2021
106   NA      03.1.2021
107   NA      10.1.2021
108   107     11.1.2021
109   NA      09.1.2021
```

I have two id variables in a data. I need to search for string sequentially.

Search 101 (`id1[1]`) in `id2`, if 101 present in `id2`, then continue and return 102 (`id1`). Again it will search for 102 in `id2` and if 102 present in id2, then continue and return 103. The process will continue and will stop when `id1` is not present in `id2`.

So output will be:

```
[[1]] 01.1.2021, 12.1.2021, 17.1.2021, 18.1.2021
```

Similarly 2nd output for id 107 will be:

```
[[2]] 10.1.2021, 11.1.2021
```

Comment: Could you add a table with your desired output? I am not exactly sure if you are asking.

Comment: The output will be a vector of dates. Check output [[1]] and [[2]]

Comment: You may check `igraph::components`. See e.g. [identify groups of linked episodes which chain together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12170710) and Linked therein.

Comment: Are you looking for a function which given an id returns a date string or to add a column of such date strings to the input or both?  Please be specific and edit the question to clarify what it is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple recursive function that jumps to the next `id2`for each entry. But you have to be cautious not to include circular references in `id1` and `id2`. Otherwise, you get endless recursion:

```
dscan = function(df,init=101){
  ni = (1:dim(df)[1])[df$id2==init & !is.na(df$id2)][1] ## Get the next line of df that fulfills the condition that id2 is the current id1
  nv = c(df$date[df$id1==init]) ## Current date
  if(!is.na(ni)>0){
    nx = df$id1[ni[1]]          ## Next index
    return(c(nv,dscan(df,nx)))  ## Recursion step
  } else {return(c(nv))}        ## Abort recursion if there is no next ni
}
```

The output would be:

```
> dscan(df,101)
[1] "01.1.2021" "12.1.2021" "17.1.2021" "18.1.2021"
> dscan(df,107)
[1] "10.1.2021" "11.1.2021"
> dscan(df,108)
[1] "11.1.2021"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but it gets the job done:

```
library(zoo)

df %>%
  subset(id1 %in% id2 | id2 %in% id1) %>%
  mutate(id1 = na.locf(ifelse(is.na(id2), id1, NA))) %>%
  group_by(id1) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(toString(unique(.)))) %>%
  select(date)
```

Which returns:

```
  date                                      
  <chr>                                     
1 01.1.2021, 12.1.2021, 17.1.2021, 18.1.2021
2 10.1.2021, 11.1.2021
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** We will assume that what is wanted is an additional column which gives a comma separated string of dates.  To do that we form a recursive common table expression (CTE) in SQL.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("with recursive R(id1, id2, date) as (
    select * from DF a where a.id1 = id1
    union all
    select a.id1, a.id2, R.date from DF a join R on a.id1 = R.id2
)
  select a.*, group_concat(r.date) dates 
  from DF a 
  left join R on a.id1 = R.id1
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  id1 id2      date                                   dates
1 101  NA 01.1.2021 01.1.2021,12.1.2021,17.1.2021,18.1.2021
2 102 101 12.1.2021           12.1.2021,17.1.2021,18.1.2021
3 103 102 17.1.2021                     17.1.2021,18.1.2021
4 104 103 18.1.2021                               18.1.2021
5 105  NA 25.1.2021                               25.1.2021
6 106  NA 03.1.2021                               03.1.2021
7 107  NA 10.1.2021                     10.1.2021,11.1.2021
8 108 107 11.1.2021                               11.1.2021
9 109  NA 09.1.2021                               09.1.2021
```

**2)** If instead what is wanted is a function that takes the data frame and id and produces the date string then use the following. (Note that if id were character rather than numeric then $id at the end of the first select line should be replaced with '$id' .)

```
library(sqldf)

get_dates <- function(data, id) {
  fn$sqldf("with recursive R(id1, id2, date) as (
    select * from DF where id1 = $id
    union all
    select a.id1, a.id2, a.date from DF a join R on a.id2 = R.id1
)
  select group_concat(date) dates from R")$dates
}

get_dates(DF, 101)
## [1] "01.1.2021,12.1.2021,17.1.2021,18.1.2021"

get_dates(DF, 107)
## [1] "10.1.2021,11.1.2021"
```

We could use this function to generate the output in (1):

```
transform(DF, dates = sapply(id1, get_dates, data = DF))
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(id1 = 101:109, id2 = c(NA, 101L, 102L, 103L, NA, 
NA, NA, 107L, NA), date = c("01.1.2021", "12.1.2021", "17.1.2021", 
"18.1.2021", "25.1.2021", "03.1.2021", "10.1.2021", "11.1.2021", 
"09.1.2021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```