# Create highest-order sets from pairs

Tags: r

I have input data that looks like this, where columns are pairs of IDs:

```
dat <- data.table(ID1 = c('A','B','C','X','B','X','F','E','G','F','A'),
              ID2 = c('B','C','A','A','X','C','J','J','I','E','I'))
```

I would like a function to generate the highest-order sets from these pairs, i.e. sets where all members are paired in the original data. In the case of the example data, I would expect the output to be:

```
list(c('A','B','C','X'),
 c('E','F','J'),
 c('G','I'),
 c('A','I'))
```

Any ideas?

*Edit:* To clarify differences from related StackOverflow post thttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135971/identify-groups-of-linked-episodes-which-chain-together, I would like groups where relationships are not inferred using pairs, but those relationships which are supported by *all* pairs. In the example data, see how (A,I) is a different set than (A,B,C,X) because pairs (B,I), (C,I), and (X,I) do not exist.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135971/identify-groups-of-linked-episodes-which-chain-together

Comment: Here's another igraph solution that gets close: `igraph::cluster_edge_betweenness(igraph::graph_from_data_frame(dat, directed=FALSE))`.