How to group by one column and then a second column to summarize
I have a data frame with two ID fields similar to the following:



ID 1
ID 2
Name




5
6
Apple1


5
7
Applee


6
7
Applye


3
7
Apple2



I am trying to first group by the first ID then by the second, so that all associations are grouped together. ID 5 would be grouped to 6 and 7, but also 3 because of 3's association with 7. The result will look something like this (though where the paired IDs end up doesn't matter to me):



ID 1
ID 2
Name




5
6,7,3
Apple1, Applee, Applye, Apple2



I have scoured the internet for a way to do this but can't seem to figure it out. A simple group_by wasn't working because I need to do something with the other ID field, like concatenate it the matches, which then prevents me from grouping on the second ID (though I thought there might be a way to group by matches to a list using grepl or something).

I think this is another chance for application of this sort of code, using a graph package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135971/identify-groups-of-linked-episodes-which-chain-together

As suggested by the thelatemail, we can use the igraph package to convert the data into a graph, and then determine the group membership. Then, some tidyverse functions to get the required output.
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)

data.frame(group=components(g)$membership, 
           ID1=as.numeric(names(components(g)$membership))) |>
  inner_join(df, by="ID1") |>
  summarise(.by=group, 
            ID_1=first(ID1), 
            ID_2=paste(unique(c(ID1,ID2)), collapse=","), 
            Name=paste(Name, collapse=",")) |>
  separate_longer_delim(ID_2, delim=",") |>
  filter(ID_1!=ID_2) |>
  summarise(.by=group, ID1=first(ID_1), 
            ID2=paste(ID_2, collapse=","),
            Name=first(Name))


  group ID1   ID2                        Name
1     1   5 6,3,7 Apple1,Applee,Applye,Apple2


Edit: (thanks to @M--)
data.frame(group=components(g)$membership, 
           ID1=as.numeric(names(components(g)$membership))) |>
  inner_join(df1, by="ID1") |>
  summarise(.by=group, 
            ID_1=first(ID1), 
            ID_2=paste(unique(c(ID1,ID2)) |> 
                 (\(x) x[x != first(ID1)])(), collapse=","),
            Name=paste(Name, collapse=","))      

Which is a nicer way to remove the repeated value of ID1 from ID2.

df <- structure(list(ID1 = c(5, 5, 6, 3), ID2 = c(6, 7, 7, 7), Name = c("Apple1", 
"Applee", "Applye", "Apple2")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))


Nice one. In your first summarise, you can write ID_2=paste(unique(c(ID.1,ID.2)) |> (\(x) x[x != first(ID.1)])(), collapse=","), ... which eliminates the need for separate, filter, and the second summarize.

Here's a similar approach as the one of Edward's:
read.table(text = "ID.1     ID.2    Name
                   5    6   Apple1
                   5    7   Applee
                   6    7   Applye
                   3    7   Apple2
                   10 12  Orange
                   12 13 Orangee", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) -> df1


lapply(igraph::max_cliques(tidygraph::as_tbl_graph(df1)), names) |>
(\(els){unique(sapply(els, \(x) 
  unique(unlist(els[sapply(els, \(y) any(x %in% y))]))))})() |>
  (\(ll) data.frame(grp = rep(seq_along(ll), sapply(ll, length)),
             ID.1 = unlist(ll)))() |>
  (\(dat) merge(df1, dat, sort = F))() |>
  dplyr::summarise(ID_1 = ID.1[1], 
            ID_2 = list(unique(c(ID.1,ID.2)) |> (\(id2) id2[id2 != ID.1[1]])()), 
            Name = paste(Name, collapse=","),
            .by = grp)

#>   grp ID_1    ID_2                        Name
#> 1   2    5 6, 3, 7 Apple1,Applee,Applye,Apple2
#> 2   1   10  12, 13              Orange,Orangee

Created on 2024-07-15 with reprex v2.0.2
